# Is it possible to reach bean method's annotation from within bean?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

Suppose I am initializing bean with the following code:

```
@Configuration 
MyConfig {
    @Bean
    @MyAnnotation // how to know this from bean constructor or method?
    MyBean myBean() {
       MyBean ans = new MyBean();
       /// setup ans
       return ans;
    }
}
```

Can I know from withing bean constructor or from withing bean's methods something about `@MyAnnotation` annotation?

Not from within `myBean()` method, which is obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by "something"? Is your annotation a runtime retention annotation? Does the `MyBean` have any information about `MyConfig` or do you expect it to know about the annotation without knowing what called it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic (1) "something" means annotation existence and it's parameters. (2) annotation is as "good" as required and it is definitely runtime (3) no (4) I expect may be Spring, when instantiating beans from annotated config, takes some information from annotations and it is accessible for beans

Answer (score 1):

Well it's probably not the best or even correct way, but my first guess is to use current stack trace and it seems to work for me:

```
package yourpackage;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AspectJRawTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("custom annotation playground");

        ISomething something = new SomethingImpl();

        something.annotatedMethod();
        something.notAnnotatedMethod();
    }

}

interface ISomething {
    void annotatedMethod();

    void notAnnotatedMethod();
}

class SomethingImpl implements ISomething {
    @MyCustomAnnotation
    public void annotatedMethod() {
        System.out.println("I am annotated and something must be printed by an advice above.");
        CalledFromAnnotatedMethod ca = new CalledFromAnnotatedMethod();
    }

    public void notAnnotatedMethod() {
        System.out.println("I am not annotated and I will not get any special treatment.");
        CalledFromAnnotatedMethod ca = new CalledFromAnnotatedMethod();
    }
}

/**
 * Imagine this is your bean which needs to know if any annotations affected it's construction
 */
class CalledFromAnnotatedMethod {
    CalledFromAnnotatedMethod() {
        List<Annotation> ants = new ArrayList<Annotation>();
        for (StackTraceElement elt : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            try {
                Method m = Class.forName(elt.getClassName()).getMethod(elt.getMethodName());
                ants.addAll(Arrays.asList(m.getAnnotations()));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored) {
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException ignored) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println(ants);
    }
}
```

Output clearly shows that I got an access to my annotation within object's constructor when it was called from annotated method:

```
custom annotation playground
I am annotated and something must be printed by an advice above.
[@yourpackage.MyCustomAnnotation(isRun=true)]
I am not annotated and I will not get any special treatment.
[]
```